# How i return the array in Firebase, swift

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a super beginner at swift.
these days I have learned how to use firebase in my project.
Basically, I prefer to make simple and short functions always in order to use it in the main code.
so I made a function that will return the array value from firebase JSON data.
But it always shows the empty, not any data.

Below is apart of my code.

```
class FunctionList: NSObject {
    var ref : fatabaseReference!
    var db : Database.database().reference()

    func CallInfo() -> (Date:Array<String>, Temper:Array<Float>){
        var _date: [String] = []
        var _temper: [Float] = []

        db.child("Location").observeSingleEvent(of: .value){ snapshot in
            var call: [String] = []
            do{
                let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: snapshot.value, option:[])
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let _site: [Location] = try decoder.decode([Location].self. from:data)
                self._site = _site

                if( _site[0].name == "Newyork"){
                    let Target = _site[0].TemperInfo
                    let lastNum:Int = Target.count
                    let startNum:Int = lastNum-5
                    for i in stride(from startNum, to:lastNum, by: +1){
                        _date.append(Target[i].Date)
                        _temper.append(Target[i].Temper)
                    }
                }
            } catch let error{
                print(" Error has occurred : \(error.localizeDescription)")
                debugPrint(error)
            }
        }
        //for i in stride(from: 0, to:5, by+1){
        //  print("\(_date[i])    \(_temper[i]) )
        //}
        return(_date, _temper)
    }

struct Location: Codable{
    let id:String
    let name: String
    let TemperInfo: [T_Info]
    var toDictionary: [String: Any]{
        let tInfoArray = TemperInfo.map{$0.toDictionary}
        let dict: [String: Any] = ["id":id, "name":name, "TemperInfo":tInfoArray]
        return dict
    }
    static var id: Int = 0    
}

struct T_Info: Codable{
    let Date: String
    let Temper: Float
    var toDictionary:[String: Any]{
        let dict: [String: Any] = ["Date": Date, "Temper":Temper]
        return dict
    }
}
```

I already check the condition of JSON data in my firebase many time.
there clearly exist the data.
and I expected the latest 5 days date and temperature via this function.
But return always "0". ( I commented out the print line at the above return line of the "CallInfo" function.)

Am I miss something? or is there a more good way to return the array that I want?

Really appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Comment: `observeSingleEvent` is asynchronous and returns immediately, before the query is complete.  If you log something just before the return, you'll see that.

Comment: Okay, then is there any way to get that data as an array?

Comment: You should be getting it in the callback.  You won't be able to return it directly from `CallInfo`, as the callback is invoked asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

As @Doug mentioned, `observeSingleEvent`, in fact nearly all fetching from remote, is asyncchronous. Meaning that the function terminates before the data arrives thus you can't return the data directly.

You should use pass in a function as an argument (usually called `callback` or `completion` of `callInfo` (and it's convention to name functions in lower camelcase), and pass the data as the argument of the callback. E.g.

```swift
func callInfo(completion: @escaping (Date:Array<String>, Temper:Array<Float>) -> Void) -> {
    // ... do your data fetching

    // now the data is ready, call the handling function with data
    completion(_date, _temper)
}

// Usage
callInfo(completion: { (date, temper) in 
    // the following two lines will execute when the data is ready
    print(date)
    print(temper)
})
```